# Can't install Go Tensorflow

Tags: linux, ubuntu, go, tensorflow

I'm trying to install Tensorflow Go on a Linux Ubuntu machine.

I have done the first 3 steps in the [Installation guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/install/install_go) and am currently at step 4.

Everything above 4) works, but I couldn't run "go get github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tensorflow/go" as instructed. The error that I'm having is:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -ltensorflow
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Exited with code 2
```

I'm pretty sure my environment path variables are configured correctly, as seen below:

```
sudo ldconfig -p | grep tensorflow
        libtensorflow_framework.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libtensorflow_framework.so
        libtensorflow.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libtensorflow.so
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You don't even tell us what the error is! What is your problem? How can we reproduce it?

Comment: Hi @peterSO , sorry about forgetting to add the error in! I have updated my question!

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the [C library](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/lang_c) first !

Look at the doc :

[image]

Assuming you're on linux without GPU, just do :

```
wget https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/libtensorflow/libtensorflow-cpu-linux-x86_64-1.12.0.tar.gz

sudo tar -xzf libtensorflow-cpu-linux-x86_64-1.12.0.tar.gz -C /usr/local

sudo ldconfig
```